# How do I determine the physical size of a quartz crystal of a given shape and vibrational mode needed to approximate a specific resonant frequency?

Tags: hard-science, engineering, materials, audio

So, one of my D&D characters has a cut/relief-carved quartz crystal amulet (medallion shaped) that's both an arcane focus (crystal) and a holy symbol (amulet), and I thought it would be a good idea for it to resonate within the audible range, given that quartz crystals can make good, pure-tone mechanical resonators.  However, I can't find much on what *size* a quartz resonator needs to be for a given shape, vibrational mode, and frequency.

In my case, I'm thinking this would be a flexural mode resonator for practicality and probably audibility/volume as well, made in a cylindrical disk shape (with relief carvings on both sides and a hole in it for wearability) to serve as an amulet, and with a resonant frequency *somewhere* in the audible range (preferably somewhere from a few hundred Hz to 15kHz).  Considering that a reasonable maximum size would be somewhere around 25mm in diameter and 5mm thick, what actual size would be needed to reach the audible frequency range?

Comment: I believe the resonant frequency has a lot to do with the speed of sound in the resonant medium (5.8km/s), if the size is a multiple of 1/4 of a wavelength then boom, resonance (although you want 1/2 a wavelength so it only vibrates in the middle). Based on the size of this [old military 2kHz quartz crystal](http://www.sinequanon.co.uk/collectors-g-e-c-radio-quartz-crystal-fjc-1848-2-1khz.html) your amulet would probably be... amulet sized. The catch is that thicker resonators are stiffer, i.e. they move less when resonating, i.e. they're going to make less noise (more movement = louder noise)

Comment: @Samwise -- what *would* the minimum thickness be for an amulet-sized quartz disc to be robust enough to withstand an adventurer's lifestyle?

Comment: *"Minimum thickness":* very thin, supposing that the adventurer knows a good jeweller who can mount the crystal in a suitable frame.

Comment: @AlexP ah, interesting point re: the frame.  What would such a frame look like?  I was originally thinking it'd be a frameless setup, but I don't think there'd be any objection to a frame being a thing

Comment: Ideally, the frame would be in the shape of [Euterpe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euterpe), the muse of music.

Comment: Now, if **I** was the adventurer I would prefer to carry a [singing bowl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_bell), which has the advantage of making a loud sound, perfectly tuned to a given pitch.

Comment: @AlexP -- yeah, unfortunately, I'm limited in the forms I can make this -- the resonance is sort of a "bonus" thing :)

Comment: @Shalvenay well, quartz is pretty damn tough, I recon you'd be able to have a disk no thicker than the average coin and even then it'd be pretty hard to break, high quality fused quartz is tougher than standard glass

Comment: @Samwise -- so, in the 1-2mm thick range...that sounds workable :)

Comment: If we just divide 5,800m/s by 10,000Hz, we get 58cm, a pretty large amulet! How did we get into 1-2mm range?

Comment: @AndrisBirkmanis -- the 1-2mm is thickness not diameter :)

Comment: Note that quartz is somewhat piezoelectric (that's the reason it is used in quartz clocks), so if it would resonate due to non-electrical stimuli it might produce some unwanted electric shocks

Comment: Your audible amulet would need some magic power source ! Producing audible sound will involve considerable amplitude. How would your amulet come to start resonating ? It would need energy to start moving and also it would need energy to compensate for losses that would make the resonance fade out within (milli-)seconds.

Comment: @Goodies -- this is a "what note does it make when it is rung/struck" thing, just like a tuning fork

Comment: Why do you need to ask this question? Do you have an electrical engineer or a clock manufacturer in your D&D group? The idea passes suspension of disbelief just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you can't, because there's no closed form of computing the vibration modes, except for the very simple *and very uniform* geometries.
Even then some 'weird' function may need to be invented - for example, the [vibration modes for a circular membrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane) will use the [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) - which are defined as "they are the *elementary* solutions for the circular membrane vibration equation, all the other vibrations mode will be a combination/superposition of them"

To make the matter worse for your case, the carving in an amulet will drastically modify these vibration modes. What appears yo you as just a small indentation will modify the timbre of the vibrating element, by tuning down some harmonics. With a careful adjustment of such "engraving", one can tune down the fundamental frequency and enhance the first harmonic (harder to do then the reverse, but still possible).

As an example in which even simple vibrating elements are tuned, go no further than tongue based instruments, in which the vibration is the one of a "tongue" with a clamped end and the other free (for example [slit drums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slit_drum) - some with an [exceptionally well tuned sound](https://www.youtube.com/c/WoodPackDrums/videos)).
Some [may tell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnCgbzXg2RY) you [it not a big deal](https://youtu.be/PpQ9Lfg0vTc?t=605) to tune it, that it's actually a [brain dead simple to make and tune one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKXhOwwIwcA). Yet, if you really want a fine one, [you are going to have surprises of the unpleasant kind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zV7yQlSvVmU).

Even harder when you get on making something from solid surfaces - [it will take days](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0O6SFM48Fc) for someone already an expert [to make one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJd_ym6c0ks).

Bottom line - it's hard because the vibration modes for anything else but simple shapes and homogeneous materials are not entirely captured by science in easy formulas that are amenable to engineering. This is where artistry, craftsmanship (and maybe magic) have lots of room to play.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to simply get the approximate fundamental frequency for a given size and mode, we can disregard the carvings for that approximation even I reckon

Comment: Highly depends on the shape. With circular shapes (and no holes), you go with the Bessel functions that I linked above (take the fundamental mode). For elliptic shape, you go with the equivalent [Mathieu functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function). The rectangular membranes [are easier](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VibrationOfARectangularMembrane/).

Comment: fr sufficient audible sound it also has to have sufficient change in its shape or have some amplifier - that's why a plate may sound, aka glass dish or a glass cup, being a sort of membrane, but same size chunk of same material won't produce that much sound.
yeah, the question is anything but trivial, but interesting. I think the answer lacks any example which does not require clicking links, I mean a glass rod will make sound, even if it won't work for op's sizes but it is a starting point at least. nice youtube link btw.

Answer (score -1):

A [modern 20kHz tuning fork crystal](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/epson/C-2-20-0000K-P-PBFREE/SER3301-ND/1022094), as used in electronics, is housed in a cylinder 6mm in length and 2mm in diameter. Assuming the frequency scales linearly with size, you would probably get something up to the size of a thumb depending on desired frequency.

Comment: This answer fails to take into account that tuning-fork crystals are named such because they are physically cut in a fork-like shape, and vibrate accordingly as a result.  [This presentation from a crystal manufacturer](http://www.nkg.com.hk/pdf/NKG-TIT_TuningForkCrystals.pdf) is a good summary of how they work.

Comment: I think you are right on the money with the tuning fork crystals, and Shalvenay has a perfect link for the background of those things. Looking at that material, a hollow, thickwalled disk ( for protection) with one or more internal forks and a small-aperture hole for listening would be ideal. The building of such a magnificent contraption from one piece would surely be only possible with elven magics and dwarven cunning, but if one were to manufacture it as two pieces, and later glue it, even a gifted artificer might be able to produce it....

Comment: The cylinder has very little to do with the frequency. If you cut the cylinder open you'll see the crystal takes up a very small amount of the cylinder.

The resonance frequency of a quartz crystal is based on its size, shape, and the electric charge applied to it.